# Can I transfer an Application and its data to a different Mac

Tags: macos, mac, applications, data-transfer

I was given a MacBook Air to use as a laptop for school in the sixth grade. Now I am graduating and heading off to high school, so I need to turn my laptop in for good. Now I have had this laptop for a long time, and customized everything just the way I like it. For example in my browser, Opera, I have added many extensions, userscripts, and customized it just the way I like it. Now I would like to transfer this browser along with all of its data, to my personal MacBook Pro. 
Is there an easy way to do this? I believe that the data is stored under:

> User > Library > Application Support > "Application's Name" / "com.Application's Website"

Though I am not positive of this, but if the data *actually* is in there then I could just copy the contents of it and put it into the same file on my MacBook Pro. I would rather not do this unless I have to, in-case I mess something up.

I feel like there should be an easier way of doing this. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in *Migration Assistant* to move your settings, apps, and documents to the new computer.

> Move your content to a new Mac Use Migration Assistant to copy all of
>   your documents, apps, user accounts, and settings to a new Mac from
>   another computer.

[Here's](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350) a document about how to use it (although it's pretty simple and it looks like you're an experienced Mac user).  I can't say for sure that **all** your customizations will copy over but it's the easiest, most complete, and *free* option available.

Comment: Thank you, but if I am correct doesn't Migration Assistant, copy **everything** to the new Mac, overriding everything that was on the new Mac? I only wish to copy a couple applications along with their data.

Comment: I believe you can use select a subset of data from the source machine.  The application screenshot on the page shows how you can make a selection.  You can run thru it and see what it selects before deciding if you want to [use it](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/osx/elcapitan-migration-select-items.jpg).